# Django requirements file package is not installed in the selected environment

Tags: django, next.js, django-rest-framework, django-channels

I want to create a live chat project with Django and Nextjs and I'm running into a problem. I'm not sure why after installing `channels` and `channels-redis`  , when I try to import the package inside the files in not getting recognized ( `import channels.db could not be resolved` ), and in my `requirements.txt` file those 2 packages show as `package is not installed in the selected environment` .

And I'm getting this error `WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/' failed:`  (I've tried with `ws://localhost:8000/` too) when my frontend tries to access the backend.

Please let me know what can I do to fix this. Thank you!

I've tried to create this project with virtualenv and poetry, and I get the same problem with both.

This is the code I have for the chat :

settings.py file:

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'backend.wsgi.application'
ASGI_APPLICATION = "backend.asgi.application"
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("redis", "6379")],
        },
        }
    }
```

asgi.py file

```
import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from . import routing

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'backend.settings')

django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

# application = get_asgi_application()
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": django_asgi_app,
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

routing.py file :

```
from django.urls import re_path
from chat.consumers import ChatConsumer

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/chat/', ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

consumers.py file :

```
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
from .models import Message


class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_group_name = 'chat'
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    @database_sync_to_async
    def create_message(self, message, username):
        message_obj = Message.objects.create(
            content=message,
            username=username
        )
        return message_obj

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        data = json.loads(text_data)
        message = data['message']
        username = data['username']

        # Create a new message object and save it to the database
        message_obj = await self.create_message(message, username)

        # Send the message to the group
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message_obj.content,
                'username': message_obj.username,
                'timestamp': str(message_obj.timestamp)
            }
        )

    async def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']
        username = event['username']
        timestamp = event['timestamp']

        # Send the message to the websocket
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message,
            'username': username,
            'timestamp': timestamp
        }))
```

and this is the frontend :

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import useWebSocket, { ReadyState } from "react-use-websocket";

const ChatEngine = (props) => {
  const [showChat, setShowChat] = useState(false);
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [welcomeMessage, setWelcomeMessage] = useState("");

  const { readyState } = useWebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8000/", {
    onOpen: () => {
      console.log("Connected!");
    },
    onClose: () => {
      console.log("Disconnected!");
    },
    // New onMessage handler
    onMessage: (e) => {
      console.log(e);
    },
  });

  const connectionStatus = {
    [ReadyState.CONNECTING]: "Connecting",
    [ReadyState.OPEN]: "Open",
    [ReadyState.CLOSING]: "Closing",
    [ReadyState.CLOSED]: "Closed",
    [ReadyState.UNINSTANTIATED]: "Uninstantiated",
  }[readyState];

  console.log("connection status: ", connectionStatus);
```

Comment: check if channels is installed in your env by running `pip freeze | grep channels`

Comment: Hi, that command is actually returning me the versions of channels and channels-redis  channels==4.0.0 channels-redis==4.1.0

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Questions typically receive faster and better answers if they include a [mre]. Also, it often helps to include the full error message.